# How do I make columns with CSS flexbox that include images?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a multi-column layout in CSS with flexbox. For screens 1025px or higher, I want it to be a 3 column layout. Between a screen width of 720px to 1025px, I want there to be only 2 columns. I've tried in many ways to make this happen, but I seem to only be able to create the 3 columns I want. Here is the code I used to create my 3 columns:

```css
.deals {
  text-align: center;
}

.deal {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.deal img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

@media (min-width: 720px) {
  /* columns for home page */
  .deals {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="deals clearfix">

  <div class="deal_1 deal clearfix">
    <h2>Guitars <span class="orange-word">40%</span> off</h2>
    <img alt="electric guitar" src="img/guitar-deal.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="deal_2 deal clearfix">
    <h2><span class="orange-word">$200</span> Amplifier</h2>
    <img alt="amplifier" src="img/amplifier-deal.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="deal_3 deal clearfix">
    <h2><span class="orange-word">$100</span> Microphone</h2>
    <img alt="Microphone" src="img/mircophone-set-deal.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you’re looking for “columns”, have you played with CSS grid—either to replace or use with flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the small screen, set the elements flex-basis to 40%. This makes the total number of items per row 2. (Any number between 33% and 49% will do).

On the media query, set them to 30% (any number between 33 and 25 will do).

To move the last item to the left, add 2 empty elements

```css
.deals {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.deal {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.deal img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  /* adjust to 3 columns */
  .deal {
    flex-basis: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="deals clearfix">

  <div class="deal_1 deal clearfix">
    <h2>Guitars <span class="orange-word">40%</span> off</h2>
    <img alt="electric guitar" src="img/guitar-deal.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="deal_2 deal clearfix">
    <h2><span class="orange-word">$200</span> Amplifier</h2>
    <img alt="amplifier" src="img/amplifier-deal.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="deal_3 deal clearfix">
    <h2><span class="orange-word">$100</span> Microphone</h2>
    <img alt="Microphone" src="img/mircophone-set-deal.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="deal"></div>
  <div class="deal"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, the flex basis properties and flex grow properties do not affect my images at all. In the media query and outside of it

Comment: Just simply writing display: flex displays all of my image columns onto the same line, I'm not sure why the flex basis and flex grow is not working.

Comment: Have you noticed that in the snippet I set flex-wrap: wrap; ?

Comment: Oops! you're a genius... I finally got the layout I wanted, but I'm struggling with getting the layout to be 3 columns when its at 1025px or wider. I put the flex-basis: 30%; on .deals, but its still not changing. I even tried flex-wrap: nowrap; and that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Actually it's because I put the flex-wrap, and flex-basis inside a media query, and when I put the flex-basis inside the "1025px" media query, it is somehow being overridden by the first media query:

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching for "column" layout, that seems a good fit for [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).

This is the important piece here:

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

To break it down:

> **display: grid;** Gives us a grid container
>
> **[grid-template-columns:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)** Defines the column behavior for our grid
>
> **[repeat( ... , ... );](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat)** Function to define a pattern for columns or rows, here for columns. First argument is the number of repetitions--either fixed or auto--and second argument is the value we
>   want to repeat.
>
> **(auto-fit, [minmax(200px, 1fr)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax))** `auto-fit` optimizes the number of columns to the minimum and maximum constraints of the container. Here
>   using it with the `minmax()` function we define the minimum column
>   width as 200px, otherwise distribute the available width evenly. Play with this.

```css
.deals {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  text-align: center;
}

.deal img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="deals">

  <div class="deal">
    <h2>Guitars <span class="orange-word">40%</span> off</h2>
    <img alt="electric guitar" src="img/guitar-deal.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="deal">
    <h2><span class="orange-word">$200</span> Amplifier</h2>
    <img alt="amplifier" src="img/amplifier-deal.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="deal">
    <h2><span class="orange-word">$100</span> Microphone</h2>
    <img alt="Microphone" src="img/mircophone-set-deal.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that's what you want.

```css
.deals {
  text-align: center;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.deal {
  width:100%;
}

.deal img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width:1025px) {
  .deals {
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  /* columns for home page */
  .deals {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="deals clearfix">

  <div class="deal_1 deal clearfix">
    <h2>Guitars <span class="orange-word">40%</span> off</h2>
    <img alt="electric guitar" src="img/guitar-deal.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="deal_2 deal clearfix">
    <h2><span class="orange-word">$200</span> Amplifier</h2>
    <img alt="amplifier" src="img/amplifier-deal.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="deal_3 deal clearfix">
    <h2><span class="orange-word">$100</span> Microphone</h2>
    <img alt="Microphone" src="img/mircophone-set-deal.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```